# How can I get rid of the the category suffix--NOT "prefix" (i.e. foo-1, foo-2, etc)

Tags: categories, urls, slug

I just added a new category to my WordPress site, but the WP is adding a "-2" to the url as if there was an existing category with the same name. But there isn't. There was, but I deleted it. How can I resolve this?

I'm don't mind mucking around with the database in order to manually change the values (if necessary) but I would appreciate some guidance form somebody who knows what they are doing.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Go into the trash from the category list and hit "Empty Trash".</strike>

As long as the category is in the trash, the slug is considered 'in use'.

ETA: This is obviously not right, as there's no trash in categories.  Instead, using phpMyAdmin, go to database->wp_terms, and delete the row with the category information.

[Walkthrough here.](http://www.mktstmedia.com/blog/2011/delete-wordpress-category-numbered-slug/)

Comment: Are you saying that the category section has an "empty trash" button? Because I'm not seeing anything like that. I know that the "posts" section has such a  button.

Comment: Wait, you're right - there's no 'empty trash' for categories.  I'm updating my post with some new info instead.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It worked. Although, I can't help but wonder why WP would leave behind these entries hidden in the database  after I supposedly "delete" them.